# Free massive scalar field partition function in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, path-integral, partition-function

Consider the (euclidean) path integral for the free massive scalar field in $d$ dimensions, giving the partition function

$$Z_m=\int\mathcal{D}\phi~e^{\int dx^d~\phi(\Delta-m^2)\phi}$$

with [Laplace-Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator)

$$\Delta = \sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}.$$

E.g. on the torus we can expand in Fourier modes

$$\phi = \sum_{k_1,k_2,...,k_d\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{i \vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}\psi_{\vec k}$$

where $\psi_{\vec{k}}{}^*=\psi_{-\vec{k}}$ since $\phi$ is real, and which leads to

$$\mathcal D \phi \sim \prod_{k_1,k_2,...,k_d\in\mathbb{N}}d\text{Re}(\psi_\vec{k})d\text{Im}(\psi_\vec{k})$$

and

$$\begin{align}\int dx^d~\phi(\Delta-m^2)\phi =& -\sum_{k_1,k_2,...,k_d\in\mathbb{Z}}(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{k}+m^2)|\psi_{\vec{k}}|^2\\=& -\sum_{k_1,k_2,...,k_d\in\mathbb{Z}}(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{k}+m^2)(\text{Re}(\psi_{\vec{k}})^2+\text{Im}(\psi_{\vec{k}})^2)\end{align}$$

Therefore, using Gaussian integration we get

$$\begin{align}Z_m\sim& \prod_{k_1,k_2,...,k_d\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\vec{k}\cdot\vec{k}+m^2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\vec{k}\cdot\vec{k}+m^2}}\\
=&\prod_{k_1,k_2,...,k_d\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{\pi}{\vec{k}\cdot\vec{k}+m^2}\end{align}$$

up to some numerical factor.

At this point the references I'm aware of either claim victory or throw in the towel, even though the infinite product representation of this result is just as inconvenient for numerical evaluation as the original path integral form on the first line.

I imagine this functional determinant is one of the simpler ones mathematicians have encountered. My question is:

> Has this functional determinant been actually evaluated in various dimensions? What is the resulting function and the explicit $m$ dependence?

Comment: If your really want to do the calculation on a torus, you can loop at [heat kernal expansion: user's manual](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138). You can express this determinant as the exponential of the curvature invariants of the torus.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I believe the answer is that the partition function as written diverges. But one way to make further progress is to take the logarithm of the partition function, and convert the sum into an integral as you take the volume of the torus to infinity.